# Using express, how do I load controller code changes, without server reboot?

Tags: node.js, express

Currently I can make changes to template files and see the latest changes loaded.  However, when I make changes in the controller they do not load into the codebase.  In other words, I have to reboot the dev server when I make a change to controller code.  Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: By reboot you mean "stop and restart the node app", right? You do not need to reboot the machine.

Comment: Correct @HectorCorrea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to restart your app in order to load code changes. There’s no easy way around it.

However, there are some tools that can automate the process during dev. I use [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor), like this:

1. Add `supervisor` to `devDependencies` in your `package.json` and install it.

   ```
   npm install --save-dev supervisor
   ```
2. At the top level of my project, I create an executable shell script called `./dev` with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ./node_modules/.bin/supervisor -i node_modules --no-restart-on error -- ./app.js
   ```

This tells `supervisor` to run my app (`app.js`), and to monitor the current directory and any subdirectories. It will restart the app if any `.js` file is changed. (See docs if you want to monitor other files, like `.json`.)

The `-i node_modules` flag tells `supervisor` to ignore any files in the `node_modules` subdirectory.

With the `--no-restart-on error` flag, it will *not* restart the app on error. That’s because I want to see the error; I don’t want it to continually loop, restarting and showing the error over and over again.

Bottom line: Each time I save a `.js` file or create a new one, the app restarts itself.

Comment: rather than a shell script, a more node friendly method would be to just add a `dev` script to your `package.json` with the contents of your `./dev` shell script. `npm run dev`

Answer (score 2):

> You have to restart your app in order to load code changes. There’s no way around it.

This one is actually wrong.

You can clear up require.cache and require module again, and it will be reloaded. Use modules like [hotswap](https://github.com/rlidwka/node-hotswap), which does exactly this.

That said, hotswapping a code is a common cause of memory leaks, so you really shouldn't do it on production systems.

Comment: I changed it to say there’s no easy way around it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to force a new `require("...")` for the code you changed, or use a package like `forever` that monitors changes and restarts your app (but note that restarting is nothing like live reloading of course)